# Adding new page layout like category page

Tags: page-layouts

I added a new page layout in my store and now when I want add another page layout it's replaced with the previously added layout.

Why does this happen? Can't I make more than one layout?

**EDIT**:
I added in `app/code/local/Home/Page/etc/config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Home_page>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Home_page>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <homepage translate="label">
          <label>Home_page</label>
          <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>home_page</layout_handle>
        </homepage>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

Also added `app/etc/Home_page.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Home_page>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Home_page>
  </modules>
</config>
```

And add this `app/design/frontend/default/my-theme/template/page/homepage.phtml` , that I use my layout in this page.

Comment: How did you add these layouts and where are they replaced?

Comment: @fschmengler: please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show how you added more layouts, but I suspect, what's the problem:

```
    <homepage translate="label">
      <label>Home_page</label>
      <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
      <layout_handle>home_page</layout_handle>
    </homepage>
```

The layout handle `home_page` as well as the element name `<homepage>` must be **unique**. So if you add additional layouts, and you use `<homepage>` again, it overrides the previously added `<homepage>` layout.

Comment: is there a default `homepage` layout exist in magento ?

Comment: No, the default layouts from `Mage_Page` are: empty, one_column, two_columns, two_columns_left, two_columns_right and three_columns

Comment: sorry confused with the last part of your answer. So it seems `home_page` is unique in this case. Please see my answer too. I put what I think about this as an answer :)

Comment: Your answer worked, but I add a category and set it don't show in menu and redirect it to a page but the products that added in this category doesn't show, do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the page layout

Comment: Is there any way to create a page that show a category that is not able to show in menu?

Answer (score 0):

Your activation file is wrong. it should look like this

File : `app/etc/Home_Page.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Home_Page>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Home_Page>
  </modules>
</config>
```

ie You should use `Home_Page` instead of `Home_page` everywhere.

Your config file should be

File: `app/code/local/Home/Page/etc/config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Home_Page>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Home_Page>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <homepage module="Home_Page" translate="label">
          <label>Home Page</label>
          <template>homepage/unique.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>home_page</layout_handle>
        </homepage>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

You had same problem in this file too.

There is couple of things which lags in your module. They are :

1. **you should define a layout update xml file for your module** : Use *this* file to define the custom page handle of yours. For more details, you can refer in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml`. There see the definition of `page_one_column` layout handle. You need such definition for `home_page` inside your own layout update xml file.
2. **You should define the page layout template file**. According to the modifications that I have shown above, you should define that file at `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\homepage\unique.phtml`. Use `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\1column.phtml` as reference for this.

Good luck